# Dynamics AX 2009 - Transaction not settling

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

We have an invoice and payment with a 90$ difference. The customer paid the $292.28, and didn't want the other 90$ product. The user created a return for the other 90$ but it's not settling. I've tried "Marking" the transaction and updating, but it's just not going. Anything else I can try?

[image: AX 2009 Transaction]

Comment: This is a more functional rather than technical query.  I'd suggest trying [another community](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/) or [forum](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/axapta.aspx) with the question.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll post answer when I figure it out.